# Is using VPN haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, internet

I want to buy books and movies from sites that are only specific to certain areas. I want to pay but I can't. When I use VPN I can access those page and buy. Sites like *hotstar*, *popcornflix*, etc. Is it haram to use VPN, since I ain't pirating, I am buying.

Answer (score 0):

The **VPN** is a private network which you use to enter restricted blogs in your country.

Firstly it's **halal** because you do not violate the sanctities of others and the site or server is provided to you free of charge or from the owner of your own.

If you want to know judgement about its use taken from  what its use for, In some countries, pornographic websites are blocked by government for your use In this cases it become **Haram**, because it used for haram this is another situation, another situation when  the government prevents access  important sites such as study, communication sites, or even important religious sites, because they differ with another country or with another religion. In this case it becomes permissible and may become obligatory.

**The conclusion the Govern on it from what its use for** and Allah know.

Comment: I can't tell what this answer says.

Comment: its say sometimes its halal and sometimes its haram and sometimes you must used upon to what you use it for

Comment: I edit for you read it agin

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing content either restricted by **your country** or by **Sharia** then VPN is haraam. Because obeying laws of your country is part of faith from the below evidence.

> Allah, may He be exalted, says (interpretation of the meaning): “O you
> who believe! Fulfill (your) obligations” [al-Maa’idah 5:1] and the
> words of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him):
> “Muslims are bound by their conditions, except a condition that
> forbids something permissible or permits something forbidden.” Abu
> ‘Eesa [at-Tirmidhi] said: This is a hasan saheeh hadith. It was
> classed as saheeh by Shaykh al-Albaani (may Allah have mercy on him)
> in Saheeh Ibn Maajah (2353).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using it for the wrong purposes (haram or sinful), it's completely fine since VPNs are used to protect the Internet.

Answer (score -2):

Inshallah, it is haram to use any website which contains explicitly haram content. If they profit from any haram activities or content then the entire site and network is haram. Any dealing with those who do haram is itself haram. This includes generating revenue for them by surfing their websites or using their encryption. We must avoid helping those who do evil. Therefore, using a VPN to protect anonymity is halal if the VPN restricts haram content from its servers and networks. If a VPN or a website or a service deals in haram it is haram. The mufti of the tyrant is also a tyrant. Allah knows best.

This is according to Sheikh Khalid Yasin, https://www.khalidyasin.com/

Comment: VPNs don't *always* cause Haram. Many Muslims in Israel use those to access Muslim websites that are banned over there.